# Front-end + Back-end development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend, backend

I've been really getting into Ruby on Rails. I want make great apps that don't just function well but look really nice as well, and I'm worried I might not pick the right front-end language to compliment RoR development. My question is how do you simultaneously prepare for both back-end and front-end? Summer is coming up and I'm already enrolled in a few RoR classes, but am trying to choose some great front-end courses as well. Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Nice you are willing to learn. I can only encourage you. If I were you I would check youtube tutorials, try some good websites like [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com) which teach you rails for zombies (fun and well explained).

Comment: Rails for Zombies is awesome. For templating engines I would say there's not very much to learn but a lot to get used to. For instance Eruby, Erb, Erubis, Haml are all great templating engines that you may need for your ror front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Sam --

TLDR; Know HTML and CSS like the back of your hand.  Spend time learning intermediate and advanced javascript.  Its libraries are powerful, its frameworks provide a rich client experience, and its not going away anytime soon.

I've been a RoR developer for two years.  When I was first learning Ruby, and coding principles in general, its common to want to learn and learn all kinds of different stuff.  While it's tempting, I would suggest the opposite -> Hyperfocus.

Rails is a robust framework, spend some time with it.  I will agree that Rails views are very bare bones and I do not like the way they organize javascript and stylesheet logic.  It is very loose.  But, unless you're building a huge app, organizing .js and .css files isn't super important.

As far as looks go, html and css are the backbone.  There's literally a javascript library for everything you could want to do from a UI/UX perspective, so focus on intermediate/advanced js.  That will make opening doors to robust client side js frameworks like angular, ember, and backbone much easier down the road using Rails as simply an API.

Lastly, one of the hardest things to find in the industry is a great designer who can also code, or a great software engineer who can also design.  If you really care about UI/UX get some books on fundamental web design principles; they go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I encourage you to first code a few apps with the default rails stack and after that start to poke other front end options with rails as back end api.
Stay comfortable with rails first, has a lot of good tools and is enough for most of the apps you may want to build, mainly on the first stage of your learning path.